# Notation for and application of a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

If I define a diffeomorphism $\phi: \Sigma_{a} \rightarrow \Sigma_{b}$, can I also write $\phi: \Sigma_{a} \backslash A \rightarrow \Sigma_{b} \backslash B$ (for some appropriate $A$, $B$) and mean correctly the same $\phi$ operating on a restricted domain, and how, given some definition of $\phi$ do I state that $\Sigma_{d}$ is not diffeomorphically related to $\Sigma_{c}$ by $\phi$? Do I have to say e.g. $\phi:\Sigma_{c} \rightarrow \Sigma_{c}' \neq \Sigma_{d}$

Or, to ask the question another way, how do I define a diffeomorphism to mean a function that can be applied to different domains and state whether, given two particular $\Sigma$, $\phi$ is or is not a diffeomorphism between them?

What's the right terminology and notation here?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735121/g-a-restriction-of-a-homeomorphic-function-f-g-also-homeomorphic) provides a good answer in the context of homeomorphisms, and since diffeomorphisms are suitably differentiable homeomorphisms the same should apply.

In brief, for some diffeomorphism $\phi:A \rightarrow B$, and subsets $A' \subset A$ and $B'=\phi(A') \subset B$, one defines the *restriction* of $\phi$ as e.g. $\phi':A \rightarrow B$ given by $\phi'(a) = \phi(a) \ \forall a \in A'$

One may also write a *restriction* as e.g. $\phi |_{A'}$

Given such a definition in terms of the image of a subset for which the original diffeomorphism is $\phi$ defined, the restriction $\phi'$ is also necessarily a diffeomorphism, or, to quote from the chapter "Smooth Maps" [here](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441999818-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1342903-p174117361) (from J.M. Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 218, Springer)

"The restriction of a diffeomorphism to an open submanifold with or without
boundary is a diffeomorphism onto its image."