# Restriction of a covering map on a saturated set is again a covering map, the very final step of the proof.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I was reading "Munkres, *Topology* 2ed, p338-339".
It is about theorem 53.2.
The last sentence of the proof, '$V_\alpha\cap E_0$ is mapped homeomorphically onto $U\cap B_0$ by $p$' is so implicit that I can't touch the detailed stuff.

So I made my own proof below, which uses only elementary facts.
In my proof, there are two **questionmarks** in (4) and (5), at which **I used an equation that is not generally accepted** : $f(A)\cap f(B)=f(A\cap B)$.
Sorry for a complicated proof, but please let me know that my proof is valid or how I can modify it.

[Definition, *evenly covered*]
Suppose $p:E\to B$ is surjective and continuous.
An open set $U$ in $B$ is evenly covered by $p$ if $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of $V_\alpha$ and $V_\alpha\cong U$(homeomorphic by $p$) for each $\alpha$.

[Definition, *covering map*] Suppose $p:E\to B$ is surjective and continuous.
$p$ is said to be a covering map if, for each $b\in B$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ that is evenly covered by $p$.

> [Theorem]
>   Let $p:E\to B$ be a covering map.
>   If $E_0=p^{-1}(B_0)$, (said differently, $E_0$ is saturated) then the restriction $p_0=p|_{E_0}:E_0\to B_0$ is a covering map.

[My proof]
Suppose $b_0\in B_0$.
Since $p:E\to B$ is a covering map and $b_0\in B$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $b_0$ that is evenly covered.
So there exists a collection of disjoint open sets $\{V_\alpha\}$ such that
$$\bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha=p^{-1}(U)\tag{1}$$
and
$$V_\alpha\cong U(\text{homeomorphic by $p$}).\tag{2}$$

Now consider $B_0\cap U$ and $\{E_0\cap V_\alpha\}$.
$B_0\cap U$ is an open set in $B_0$ which contains $b_0$, so it is a neighborhood of $b_0$.
Note also that for each $\alpha$, $E_0\cap V_\alpha$ is disjoint one another.
It follows from (1) and $E_0=p^{-1}(B_0)$ that
\begin{align*}
E_0\cap\bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha&=p^{-1}(B_0)\cap p^{-1}(U)\\
\bigcup_\alpha(E_0\cap V_\alpha)&=p^{-1}(B_0\cap U).
\end{align*}

In order for $B_0\cap U$ be evenly covered by $p_0$, it suffices to prove that
$$E_0\cap V_\alpha\cong B_0\cap U(\text{homeomorphic by }p_0).\tag{3}$$
The fact that $p_0$ is continuous and injective is trivial since $p_0$ is a restriction of a continuous and injective map $p$.
Surjectivity of $p_0$ is immediate from
$$p_0(E_0\cap V_\alpha)=p(E_0\cap V_\alpha)\stackrel?{=}p(E_0)\cap p(V_\alpha)\stackrel{(2)}=B_0\cap U.\tag{4}$$
It remains to prove that $p_0$ has a continuous inverse, that is, $p_0$ is an open map.

Consider an open set $E_0\cap V_\alpha\cap W$ in $E_0\cap V_\alpha$ where $W$ is open in $E$.
Since $V_\alpha\cap W$ is open in $V_\alpha$, (2) implies that $p(V_\alpha\cap W)$ is open in $U$.
So $p(V_\alpha\cap W)=T\cap V$ where $T$ is open in $B$.
Thus
$$p_0(E_0\cap V_\alpha\cap W)=p(E_0\cap V_\alpha\cap W)\stackrel?=p(E_0)\cap p(V_\alpha\cap W)
=B_0\cap T\cap U\tag{5}$$
is an open set in $B_0\cap U$.
Therefore, $p_0$ is indeed an open map, $B_0\cap U$ is evenly covered by $p_0$, and $p_0$ is an open mapping.

Comment: The equation $f(A)\cap f(B)=f(A\cap B)$ does hold if $f$ is injective. In (4) and (5), $p$ (or $p_0$) is guaranteed to be injective. So the equalities with questionmarks is in fact legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but why do you want to ignore the fact that the $p_\alpha : V_\alpha \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} U$ are homeomorphisms? You correctly prove that $p_0^{-1}(B_0 \cap U) = \bigcup_\alpha E_0 \cap V_\alpha$, where the $V'_\alpha = E_0 \cap V_\alpha$ are pairwise disjoint open subsets of $E_0$. But $p_0 \mid_{V'_\alpha} = p \mid_{V'_\alpha} = p_\alpha \mid_{V'_\alpha}$, thus $p_0 \mid_{V'_\alpha}$ is the restriction of the homeomorphism $p_\alpha$ and thus maps $V'_\alpha$ homeomorphically onto $p_\alpha(E_0 \cap V_\alpha) =  B_0 \cap U$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Suppose $f:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism and let $A_0\subset A$. Does it follow that $f|_{A_0}:A_0\to f(A_0)$ is a homeomorphism? I think you are pointing out this fact. And this seems hold indeed as in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735121/g-a-restriction-of-a-homeomorphic-function-f-g-also-homeomorphic)

Comment: @shyzealot Yes, that is correct!